# Scalability of TPL Dataflow Library?

Tags: .net

How scalable is the Dataflow library? For my application, I have two specific cases in mind for when I would need to scale up:

1. Two separate applications running on the same computer, each one running their own Dataflow network.
2. Similar to situation 1, but the applications are being run on separate computers that are on the same LAN.

For each of these situations, how might I be able to link blocks that are running in separate applications?

At first thought, it seems like TCP/IP sockets could be used by blocks in separate applications to communicate with each other, but I am wondering if there are better approaches.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should try scaling up the Dataflow library and come back here with any problems you have - we can then help fix those problems. Similarly, try to implement sockets and when you have any problems come back here with them.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm trying to save myself some time in case there are better, known approaches to scaling up Dataflow implementations. I am hoping for something provided by the library itself but I didn't see anything in Microsoft docs.

Comment: I appreciate your desire to save yourself some time, but in my experience you'll make things worse for yourself. Only by doing it yourself will you understand the limits of the technology. I'm not sure if anyone here can give you a practical answer to such a broad question.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you're left the realms of the Dataflow library and you're taking about intra-machine and inter-machine communication. That kind of communication is likely to be your bottleneck. So the likely answer to your question is "Dataflow is really scalable, but as soon as you introduce any out-of-process communication you can't tell what happens until you try it." If anyone gives you an answer other than that I'd be surprised and incredulous.